# Is it possible to either JOIN or CONC or MERGE values from a list in a column to generate a dynamic formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, array-merge

Is it possible to either JOIN or CONC or MERGE values from a list in a column to generate a dynamic formula like this:

How can I echo "left(' INSERT VAR HERE '!A1:A9;0) & ' INSERT VAR HERE '!A1\' INSERT VAR HERE '!B1:F9\row(' INSERT VAR HERE '!A1:A9)-row(' INSERT VAR HERE '!A1);"?

Where VAR is from a list/column i.e. A with an unspecified number of rows containing text?

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vbmqjOFDTjPJHUos-bEdvN8AsXTCIip5PQ6HkLtJ6UA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Sr. Example added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formula to generate string:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({""; "=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({"&TEXTJOIN(";"; 1; 
 IF(Names!A2:A="Personale"; "{'"&Names!A2:A&"'!A3:F9\ROW(A1:A7)-0,1}";
 IF(Names!A2:A="Pauser";    "{'"&Names!A2:A&"'!A3:F9\ROW(A1:A7)+0,1}";
 IF(Names!A2:A<>""; "QUERY('"&Names!A2:A&"'!A3:F9; ""select '"&REGEXREPLACE(Names!A2:A; "-Klasse"; )&"',B,C,D,E,F,A label '"&REGEXREPLACE(Names!A2:A; "-Klasse"; )&"'''"")"; ))))&
 "}; ""select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6 where Col2 is not null or Col3 is not null or Col4 is not null or Col5 is not null or Col6 is not null order by Col7,Col1""))"})
```

---

then you copy cell **C3** and paste that formula in your **Skema** sheet/ark.